# Inconsistent return values when using regex functions

Tags: python, regex

My code is behaving strangely, and I have a feeling it has to do with the regular expressions i'm using.

I'm trying to determine the number of total words, number of unique words, and number of sentences in a text file.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import re

file = open('sample.txt', 'r')


def word_count(file):
    words = []
    reg_ex = r"[A-Za-z0-9']+"
    p = re.compile(reg_ex)
    for l in file:
        for i in p.findall(l):
            words.append(i)
    return len(words), len(set(words))

def sentence_count(file):
    sentences = []
    reg_ex = r'[a-zA-Z0-9][.!?]'
    p = re.compile(reg_ex)
    for l in file: 
        for i in p.findall(l):
            sentences.append(i)
    return sentences, len(sentences)

sentence, sentence_count = sentence_count(file)
word_count, unique_word_count = word_count(file)

print('Total word count:  {}\n'.format(word_count) + 
    'Unique words:  {}\n'.format(unique_word_count) + 
'Sentences:  {}'.format(sentence_count))
```

The output is the following:

```
Total word count:  0
Unique words:  0
Sentences:  5
```

What is really strange is that if I comment out the `sentence_count()` function, the `word_count()` function starts working and outputs the correct numbers.

Why is this inconsistency happening? If I comment out either function, one will output the correct value while  the other will output 0's. Can someone help me such that both functions work?

Comment: Add `contents = file.read()` and pass `contents` to your methods.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you can only iterate over an open file once. You need to either reopen or rewind the file to iterate over it again.

For example:

```
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
  sentence, sentence_count = sentence_count(f)
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
  word_count, unique_word_count = word_count(f)
```

Alternatively, `f.seek(0)` would rewind the file.

Comment: thanks!  I definitely didn't know that you can only iterate over an open file once -- really helpful to know.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to open and close your file properly. One way you can do this is by saving all the text first.

```
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as f:
    file = f.read()
```

The [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-with_stmt) statement can be used to open and safely close the file handle. Since you would have extracted all the contents into `file`, you don't need the file open anymore.